# 'apt-get upgrade/dist-upgrade' does a release-upgrade 17.04

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates

I have the weirdest behaviour under Ubuntu 17.04. right now. 
When I type

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade/dist-upgrade
```

it lists alle the ~1500 Packages for the upgrade to 17.10. Which I absolutley don't want. As far as I know, this should only happen with

```
sudo apt-get do-release-upgrade
```

Which when I execute it, tells me no new releases found. 
"/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades" is set to "never" which is also shown in the GUI of the "Software Updates".

Anybody can help? I just want to update the packages that currently installed.

Output of apt-get upgrade:

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  [...](had to remove those due to characterlimit
unity-system-compositor usermetricsservice xmir xml-core
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu cpp-7 fdisk g++-7 gcc-7 gir1.2-polkit-1.0 gnome-user-docs libarchive-cpio-perl libasan4 libass9 libbinutils libcamel-1.2-60
  libdrm-common libebook-1.2-19 libemf1 libevent-2.1-6 libgcc-7-dev libgflags2.2 libgfortran4 libgmime-3.0-0 libgnutls-dane0 libgoa-backend-1.0-1 libgtop-2.0-11 libhunspell-1.6-0
  libibverbs1 libllvm5.0 libllvm5.0:i386 libmirplatform16 libmirserver45 libntfs-3g872 libopencv-core3.1 libopencv-imgproc3.1 libpgm-5.2-0 libpoppler68 libpython3.6
  libpython3.6-minimal libpython3.6-stdlib libqpdf18 librhash0 libsodium-dev libstdc++-7-dev libunbound2 liburcu6 libwebpmux3 libx265-130 libxen-4.9 libxml-simple-perl
  libxtables12 linux-headers-4.13.0-21 linux-headers-4.13.0-21-generic linux-image-4.13.0-21-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-21-generic mir-platform-graphics-mesa-kms13
  mir-platform-graphics-mesa-x13 mir-platform-input-evdev7 python-asn1crypto python-certifi python3-asn1crypto python3-certifi python3.6 python3.6-minimal ruby-bcrypt-pbkdf
  ruby-mime-types-data ruby-rbnacl ubuntu-advantage-tools ubuntu-wallpapers-artful xserver-xorg-legacy
The following packages have been kept back:
  colord compiz compiz-core compiz-gnome compiz-plugins-default gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0 gnome-session-bin gnome-session-common gscan2pdf gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-tools hplip hplip-data hud i965-va-driver libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libapparmor-perl
  libapt-pkg-perl libbit-vector-perl libcairo-perl libclone-perl libcompizconfig0 libdate-calc-xs-perl libdecoration0 libfcgi-perl libfile-fcntllock-perl libfilesys-df-perl
  libglib-perl libgoo-canvas-perl libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0 libgstreamer1.0-0 libgtk2-imageview-perl libgtk2-perl libhpmud0 libhtml-parser-perl
  libhud2 libimage-magick-q16-perl libio-pty-perl liblist-moreutils-perl liblocale-gettext-perl libnet-dbus-perl libnet-libidn-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libossp-uuid-perl
  libpango-perl libparams-classify-perl libparams-validate-perl libperlio-gzip-perl libproc-processtable-perl libpython3-dev libpython3-stdlib
  libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk3
  libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math libreoffice-ogltrans libreoffice-pdfimport libreoffice-style-breeze libreoffice-style-galaxy libreoffice-style-tango
  libreoffice-writer librhythmbox-core10 libsane-common libsane-hpaio libsane-perl libsnmp30 libsocket6-perl libsub-name-perl libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl
  libunity-core-6.0-9 libuuid-perl libva-dev libva-drm1 libva-glx1 libva-tpi1 libva-wayland1 libva-x11-1 libva1 libvlc-bin libvlc5 libvlccore8 libwine libwine:i386
  libxml-libxml-perl libxml-parser-perl libyaml-libyaml-perl mpv octave octave-common onboard onboard-common onboard-data perl perl-base printer-driver-hpcups
  printer-driver-postscript-hp python3 python3-apt python3-brlapi python3-cairo python3-cffi-backend python3-crypto python3-cups python3-dbus python3-dev python3-gdbm python3-gi
  python3-gi-cairo python3-libapparmor python3-lxml python3-markupsafe python3-minimal python3-pil python3-psutil python3-renderpm python3-reportlab python3-reportlab-accel
  python3-simplejson python3-systemd python3-uno python3-yaml python3-zope.interface rename rhythmbox rhythmbox-data rhythmbox-plugins sane sane-utils simple-scan texinfo
  ubuntu-restricted-addons ubuntu-session unity unity-gtk-module-common unity-gtk2-module unity-gtk3-module unity-schemas unity-services unity-settings-daemon vainfo virtualbox
  virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-ext-pack virtualbox-qt vlc vlc-bin vlc-data vlc-l10n vlc-plugin-base vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-qt vlc-plugin-samba vlc-plugin-skins2
  vlc-plugin-video-output vlc-plugin-video-splitter vlc-plugin-visualization wine-stable wine32:i386 wine64
The following packages will be upgraded:
  accountsservice-ubuntu-schemas accountsservice-ubuntu-touch-schemas acl acpid activity-log-manager adium-theme-ubuntu adwaita-icon-theme aisleriot anacron apparmor
  apparmor-easyprof apport apport-gtk appstream apt apt-transport-https apt-utils aspell aspell-en at-spi2-core augeas-lenses autoconf automake autopoint avr-libc avrdude
  bamfdaemon baobab base-files bash bind9-host binfmt-support binutils binutils-avr bluez bluez-cups bluez-obexd brltty bsdmainutils bsdtar bsdutils build-essential
  ca-certificates ca-certificates-java cheese cheese-common chromium-browser chromium-browser-l10n chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra cifs-utils click cmake cmake-data cmake-qt-gui
  colord-data comerr-dev command-not-found command-not-found-data compizconfig-settings-manager console-setup console-setup-linux coreutils cpp cpp-5 cpp-6 cracklib-runtime cron
  cryptsetup cryptsetup-bin cups cups-browsed cups-bsd cups-client cups-common cups-core-drivers cups-daemon cups-filters cups-filters-core-drivers cups-ipp-utils cups-ppdc
  cups-server-common curl dbus dbus-user-session dbus-x11 debconf debconf-i18n debhelper debianutils default-jre-headless deja-dup desktop-file-utils dh-autoreconf
  dh-strip-nondeterminism diffstat diffutils dirmngr distro-info-data dkms dmeventd dmidecode dmsetup dns-root-data dnsmasq dnsmasq-base dnsutils dosfstools dpkg dpkg-dev
  e2fslibs e2fslibs-dev e2fsprogs ebtables efibootmgr enchant eog espeak-ng-data evince evince-common evolution-data-server evolution-data-server-common
  evolution-data-server-online-accounts ffmpeg file file-roller filezilla filezilla-common findutils firefox firefox-locale-en flashplugin-installer folks-common
  fonts-droid-fallback fonts-guru-extra fonts-kacst fonts-kacst-one fonts-lato fonts-lohit-guru fonts-lyx fonts-noto-cjk fonts-opensymbol fonts-symbola fonts-takao-pgothic
  fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-tlwg-garuda fonts-tlwg-garuda-ttf fonts-tlwg-kinnari fonts-tlwg-kinnari-ttf fonts-tlwg-laksaman fonts-tlwg-laksaman-ttf fonts-tlwg-loma
  fonts-tlwg-loma-ttf fonts-tlwg-mono fonts-tlwg-mono-ttf fonts-tlwg-norasi fonts-tlwg-norasi-ttf fonts-tlwg-purisa fonts-tlwg-purisa-ttf fonts-tlwg-sawasdee
  fonts-tlwg-sawasdee-ttf fonts-tlwg-typewriter fonts-tlwg-typewriter-ttf fonts-tlwg-typist fonts-tlwg-typist-ttf fonts-tlwg-typo fonts-tlwg-typo-ttf fonts-tlwg-umpush
  fonts-tlwg-umpush-ttf fonts-tlwg-waree fonts-tlwg-waree-ttf fonts-wine foomatic-db-compressed-ppds friendly-recovery fwupd fwupdate fwupdate-signed g++ g++-6 gcc gcc-5
  gcc-5-base gcc-6 gcc-6-base gcc-6-base:i386 gcc-avr gconf-service gconf-service-backend gconf2 gconf2-common gcr gdb gdbserver gedit gedit-common genisoimage geoclue
  geoclue-2.0 geoclue-ubuntu-geoip geoip-database gettext gettext-base ghostscript ghostscript-x gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 gir1.2-appstreamglib-1.0 gir1.2-atk-1.0 gir1.2-atspi-2.0
  gir1.2-click-0.4 gir1.2-dee-1.0 gir1.2-freedesktop gir1.2-gdata-0.0 gir1.2-gdesktopenums-3.0 gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-gee-0.8 gir1.2-glib-2.0 gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0
  gir1.2-goa-1.0 gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 gir1.2-gtk-2.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-gtk-vnc-2.0 gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 gir1.2-gudev-1.0 gir1.2-gusb-1.0 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0
  gir1.2-json-1.0 gir1.2-libosinfo-1.0 gir1.2-notify-0.7 gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 gir1.2-pango-1.0 gir1.2-peas-1.0 gir1.2-secret-1 gir1.2-soup-2.4 gir1.2-totem-1.0
  gir1.2-totem-plparser-1.0 gir1.2-udisks-2.0 gir1.2-unity-5.0 gir1.2-vte-2.91 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 gir1.2-wnck-3.0 git git-man gkbd-capplet glib-networking glib-networking-common
  glib-networking-services gnome-bluetooth gnome-calculator gnome-calendar gnome-desktop3-data gnome-font-viewer gnome-keyring gnome-mines gnome-orca gnome-power-manager
  gnome-screensaver gnome-screenshot gnome-software gnome-software-common gnome-software-plugin-snap gnome-sudoku gnome-system-log gnome-system-monitor gnome-terminal
  gnome-terminal-data gnome-tweak-tool gnome-user-guide gnome-video-effects gnupg gnupg-agent gnupg-l10n gnupg2 gnuplot gnuplot-data gnuplot-x11 gpgv grep grilo-plugins-0.3-base
  grub-common grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common gsettings-desktop-schemas gsettings-ubuntu-schemas gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps
  gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio gstreamer1.0-x gtk-update-icon-cache gtk2-engines-pixbuf gtk3-engines-breeze gucharmap gzip hicolor-icon-theme hostapd icu-devtools ifupdown
  iio-sensor-proxy im-config imagemagick imagemagick-6-common imagemagick-6.q16 indicator-appmenu indicator-bluetooth indicator-datetime indicator-keyboard indicator-messages
  indicator-power indicator-printers indicator-session indicator-sound info init init-system-helpers initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-bin initramfs-tools-core inputattach
  install-info intel-gpu-tools intel-microcode iperf ippusbxd iproute2 iptables ipxe-qemu irqbalance isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common iso-codes iucode-tool java-common joystick
  keepass2 keyboard-configuration klibc-utils kmod krb5-locales language-pack-en language-pack-en-base language-pack-gnome-en language-pack-gnome-en-base laptop-detect
  laptop-mode-tools lib32gcc1 lib32stdc++6 libaacs0 libacl1 libaec0 libaio1 libamd2 libandroid-properties1 libapparmor1 libappindicator3-1 libappstream-glib8 libappstream4
  libapt-inst2.0 libapt-pkg5.0 libarchive-tools libarchive13 libarpack2 libasan2 libasan3 libasn1-8-heimdal libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 libaspell15 libasprintf-dev libasprintf0v5
  libassuan0 libatk-adaptor libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-0:i386 libatk1.0-data libatk1.0-dev libatomic1 libatspi2.0-0 libattr1 libaudio2 libaudit-common libaudit1
  libaugeas0 libavcodec-dev libavcodec57 libavdevice57 libavfilter6 libavformat-dev libavformat57 libavresample3 libavutil-dev libavutil55 libbabeltrace-ctf1 libbabeltrace1
  libbabl-0.1-0 libbamf3-2 libbasicusageenvironment1 libbind9-140 libblas3 libblkid1 libblkid1:i386 libbluetooth-dev libbluetooth3 libbluray2 libboost-date-time1.62.0
  libboost-filesystem1.62-dev libboost-filesystem1.62.0 libboost-iostreams1.62.0 libboost-locale1.62-dev libboost-locale1.62.0 libboost-log1.62.0 libboost-program-options1.62-dev
  libboost-program-options1.62.0 libboost-random1.62.0 libboost-regex1.62.0 libboost-serialization1.62.0 libboost-system1.62-dev libboost-system1.62.0 libboost-thread1.62.0
  libboost1.62-dev libbrlapi0.6 libbsd0 libbsd0:i386 libcairo-gobject2 libcairo-script-interpreter2 libcairo2 libcairo2:i386 libcairo2-dev libcairomm-1.0-1v5 libcamd2 libcap-ng0
  libcap2 libcap2-bin libcc1-0 libccid libccolamd2 libcgi-pm-perl libcheese-gtk25 libcheese8 libcholmod3 libcilkrts5 libclick-0.4-0 libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-1.0-common
  libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcolamd2 libcolord2 libcolorhug2 libcolumbus1-common libcolumbus1v5 libcomerr2 libcomerr2:i386 libcrack2 libcroco3 libcryptsetup4 libcups2 libcups2:i386
  libcupscgi1 libcupsfilters1 libcupsimage2 libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1 libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4-openssl-dev libcxsparse3 libdatrie1 libdatrie1:i386 libdb5.3 libdb5.3:i386
  libdbus-1-3 libdbus-1-3:i386 libdbus-1-dev libdee-1.0-4 libdevmapper-event1.02.1 libdevmapper1.02.1 libdfu1 libdmapsharing-3.0-2 libdns-export162 libdns162 libdpkg-perl
  libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-dev libdrm-intel1 libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2 libdrm2:i386
  libdvbpsi10 libdw1 libebackend-1.2-10 libebml4v5 libebook-contacts-1.2-2 libebur128-1 libecal-1.2-19 libedata-book-1.2-25 libedata-cal-1.2-28 libedataserver-1.2-22
  libedataserverui-1.2-1 libedit2 libedit2:i386 libefiboot1 libefivar1 libegl1-mesa libegl1-mesa-dev libeigen3-dev libelf1 libelf1:i386 libenchant1c2a libepoxy0 libespeak-ng1
  libevdev-dev libevdev2 libevdocument3-4 libevview3-3 libexempi3 libexif12 libexiv2-14 libexpat1 libexpat1:i386 libexpat1-dev libfaad2 libfdisk1 libfdt1 libfftw3-double3
  libfftw3-single3 libfile-stripnondeterminism-perl libfilezilla0 libflite1 libfltk-gl1.3 libfltk1.3 libfolks-eds25 libfolks25 libfontembed1 libfreeimage-dev libfreeimage3
  libfreerdp-cache1.1 libfreerdp-client1.1 libfreerdp-codec1.1 libfreerdp-common1.1.0 libfreerdp-core1.1 libfreerdp-crypto1.1 libfreerdp-gdi1.1 libfreerdp-locale1.1
  libfreerdp-plugins-standard libfreerdp-primitives1.1 libfreerdp-utils1.1 libfreetype6 libfreetype6:i386 libfreetype6-dev libftdi1 libfwup1 libfwupd1 libgail-3-0 libgail-common
  libgail-common:i386 libgail18 libgail18:i386 libgbm1 libgcab-1.0-0 libgcc-5-dev libgcc-6-dev libgcc1 libgcc1:i386 libgck-1-0 libgconf-2-4 libgcr-3-common libgcr-base-3-1
  libgcr-ui-3-1 libgcrypt20 libgcrypt20:i386 libgd3 libgdata-common libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev
  libgee-0.8-2 libgegl-0.3-0 libgeis1 libgeoclue-2-0 libgeoclue0 libgeocode-glib0 libgeoip1 libgettextpo-dev libgettextpo0 libgexiv2-2 libgfortran3 libgif7 libgirepository-1.0-1
  libgksu2-0 libgl1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libglapi-mesa libglapi-mesa:i386 libgles2-mesa libgles2-mesa-dev libglew2.0
  libglewmx1.13 libglib2.0-data libglibmm-2.4-1v5 libglpk40 libgmime-2.6-0 libgnome-2-0 libgnome-bluetooth13 libgnome-desktop-3-12 libgnome-games-support-1-2
  libgnome-games-support-common libgnome2-common libgnomekbd-common libgnomekbd8 libgnutls-openssl27 libgnutls28-dev libgnutls30 libgnutls30:i386 libgnutlsxx28 libgomp1
  libgoogle-glog0v5 libgpg-error0 libgpg-error0:i386 libgpgme11 libgphoto2-6 libgphoto2-l10n libgphoto2-port12 libgpod-common libgpod4 libgraphicsmagick++-q16-12
  libgraphicsmagick-q16-3 libgraphite2-3 libgraphite2-3:i386 libgraphite2-dev libgrilo-0.3-0 libgroupsock8 libgs9 libgs9-common libgspell-1-1 libgspell-1-common libgssapi-krb5-2
  libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libgssapi3-heimdal libgssapi3-heimdal:i386 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libgtk-vnc-2.0-0 libgtk2.0-0
  libgtk2.0-0:i386 libgtk2.0-bin libgtk2.0-common libgtk2.0-dev libgtkglext1 libgtkimageview0 libgtkmm-3.0-1v5 libgtksourceview-3.0-1 libgtksourceview-3.0-common
  libgucharmap-2-90-7 libgudev-1.0-0 libgusb2 libgutenprint2 libgvnc-1.0-0 libgweather-common libgxps2 libhardware2 libhcrypto4-heimdal libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386 libhdf5-100
  libheimbase1-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 libheimntlm0-heimdal libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 libhogweed4 libhogweed4:i386 libhx509-5-heimdal libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 libhybris
  libhybris-common1 libice-dev libice6 libice6:i386 libicu-dev libicu57 libicu57:i386 libidn11 libidn11:i386 libidn11-dev libidn2-0 libimage-magick-perl libimobiledevice6
  libinput-bin libinput10 libio-socket-ssl-perl libip4tc0 libip6tc0 libipc-run-perl libiptc0 libisc-export160 libisc160 libisccc140 libisccfg140 libiscsi7 libitm1 libiw30
  libjansson4 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libjbig2dec0 libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg62:i386 libjs-sphinxdoc libjson-c3 libjson-glib-1.0-0 libjson-glib-1.0-common
  libk5crypto3 libk5crypto3:i386 libklibc libkmod2 libkpathsea6 libkrb5-26-heimdal libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 libkrb5-3 libkrb5-3:i386 libkrb5support0 libkrb5support0:i386
  liblapack3 libldap-2.4-2 libldap-2.4-2:i386 libldap-common libldb1 liblept5 libleveldb1v5 liblightdm-gobject-1-0 liblightdm-qt5-3-0 liblirc-client0 libllvm4.0 libllvm4.0:i386
  liblog-log4perl-perl liblouis-data liblouis12 liblsan0 liblttng-ust-ctl2 liblttng-ust0 liblvm2app2.2 liblvm2cmd2.02 liblwp-protocol-https-perl liblwres141 liblzma5
  liblzma5:i386 libmagic-mgc libmagic1 libmagick++-6.q16-7 libmagickcore-6.q16-3 libmagickcore-6.q16-3-extra libmagickwand-6.q16-3 libmatroska6v5 libmbedcrypto0 libmbedtls-dev
  libmbedtls10 libmbedx509-0 libmbim-glib4 libmbim-proxy libmedia1 libmediaart-2.0-0 libmessaging-menu0 libmetacity1 libminiupnpc-dev libminiupnpc10 libmiral2
  libmission-control-plugins0 libmm-glib0 libmodplug1 libmount1 libmount1:i386 libmpc3 libmpeg2-4 libmpfr4 libmpg123-0 libmpg123-0:i386 libmpx0 libmpx2 libmtp-common
  libmtp-runtime libmtp9 libmwaw-0.3-3 libmysqlclient20 libnet-dns-perl libnet-http-perl libnettle6 libnettle6:i386 libnewt0.52 libnl-3-200 libnl-genl-3-200 libnl-route-3-200
  libnm-glib-vpn1 libnm-glib4 libnm-util2 libnotify-bin libnotify4 libnpth0 libnspr4 libnspr4:i386 libnss-resolve libnss3 libnss3:i386 libnuma1 libnux-4.0-0 libnux-4.0-common
  liboauth0 libopenblas-base libopenjfx-java libopenjfx-jni libopenjp2-7 libopenmpt-modplug1 libopenmpt0 liborbit-2-0 liborc-0.4-0 libosinfo-1.0-0 libosmesa6 libosmesa6:i386
  libossp-uuid16 libp11-kit-dev libp11-kit-gnome-keyring libp11-kit0 libp11-kit0:i386 libpackagekit-glib2-18 libpam-gnome-keyring libpam-modules libpam-modules-bin libpam-runtime
  libpam-systemd libpam0g libpango-1.0-0 libpango-1.0-0:i386 libpango1.0-0 libpango1.0-dev libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386 libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386
  libpangoxft-1.0-0 libpaper-utils libpaper1 libpcap0.8 libpcap0.8:i386 libpci3 libpcre16-3 libpcre3 libpcre3:i386 libpcre3-dev libpcre32-3 libpcrecpp0v5 libpcsclite1
  libpeas-1.0-0 libpeas-common libphodav-2.0-0 libphodav-2.0-common libpipeline1 libpkcs11-helper1 libplist3 libplymouth4 libpng-dev libpng-tools libpng16-16 libpng16-16:i386
  libpoppler-glib8 libpoppler-qt5-1 libpostproc54 libprotobuf-dev libprotobuf-lite10 libprotobuf10 libproxy-tools libproxy1-plugin-gsettings libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager
  libproxy1v5 libpsl5 libpstoedit0c2a libpugixml1v5 libpulse-dev libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0 libpulse0:i386 libpulsedsp libpvm3 libpwquality-common libpwquality1
  libpython-all-dev libpython-dev libpython-stdlib libpython2.7 libpython2.7-dev libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib libqmi-glib5 libqmi-proxy libqrupdate1
  libqscintilla2-12v5 libqscintilla2-l10n libqt5concurrent5 libqt5multimediaquick-p5 libqt5multimediawidgets5 libqt5systeminfo5 libqt5test5 libqt5versit5 libqt5x11extras5
  libquadmath0 librados2 libraptor2-0 librasqal3 libraw16 librbd1 libresid-builder0c2a libroken18-heimdal libroken18-heimdal:i386 librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common libruby2.3
  libsamplerate0 libsasl2-2 libsasl2-2:i386 libsasl2-modules libsasl2-modules:i386 libsasl2-modules-db libsasl2-modules-db:i386 libsbc1 libsdl-image1.2 libsdl-ttf2.0-0
  libsdl1.2-dev libsdl1.2debian libsdl1.2debian:i386 libsdl2-2.0-0 libsdl2-dev libseccomp2 libsecret-1-0 libsecret-common libselinux1 libselinux1:i386 libsemanage-common
  libsemanage1 libsepol1 libserd-0-0 libsfml-audio2.4 libsfml-dev libsfml-graphics2.4 libsfml-network2.4 libsfml-system2.4 libsfml-window2.4 libshine3 libsignon-extension1
  libsignon-plugins-common1 libsignon-qt5-1 libsigsegv2 libsmartcols1 libsmbclient libsnapd-glib1 libsnappy1v5 libsndfile1 libsndfile1:i386 libsndfile1-dev libsnmp-base
  libsodium18 libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libsoup2.4-1 libspeechd2 libspice-server1 libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-0:i386 libsrtp0 libss2 libssh-4 libssh-gcrypt-4 libssh2-1 libssl1.0.0
  libssl1.0.0:i386 libstdc++-5-dev libstdc++-6-dev libsuitesparseconfig4 libswresample-dev libswresample2 libswscale-dev libswscale4 libsystemd0 libsystemd0:i386 libsz2 libtag1v5
  libtag1v5-vanilla libtalloc2 libtasn1-6 libtasn1-6:i386 libtasn1-6-dev libtasn1-doc libtbb2 libtcl8.6 libtdb1 libthai-data libthai0 libthai0:i386 libtiff-tools libtiff5
  libtiff5:i386 libtk8.6 libtotem-plparser-common libtotem-plparser18 libtotem0 libtsan0 libubsan0 libubuntu-app-launch4 libuchardet-dev libuchardet0 libudev-dev libudev1
  libudev1:i386 libumfpack5 libunity-control-center1 libunity-gtk2-parser0 libunity-gtk3-parser0 libunity-protocol-private0 libunity-scopes-json-def-desktop
  libunity-settings-daemon1 libunity9 libupnp6 libupower-glib3 liburi-perl liburl-dispatcher1 libusageenvironment3 libusb-0.1-4 libusb-1.0-0 libusb-1.0-0-dev libusb-1.0-doc
  libusb-dev libuuid1 libuuid1:i386 libv4l-0 libv4lconvert0 libvamp-hostsdk3v5 libvamp-sdk2v5 libvirt-bin libvirt-clients libvirt-daemon libvirt-daemon-system libvirt0 libvpx4
  libvte-2.91-0 libvte-2.91-common libvulkan-dev libvulkan1 libwacom-bin libwacom-common libwacom2 libwavpack1 libwayland-egl1-mesa libwbclient0 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37
  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2 libwebp6 libwhoopsie-preferences0 libwhoopsie0 libwind0-heimdal libwind0-heimdal:i386 libwinpr-crt0.1 libwinpr-dsparse0.1 libwinpr-environment0.1
  libwinpr-file0.1 libwinpr-handle0.1 libwinpr-heap0.1 libwinpr-input0.1 libwinpr-interlocked0.1 libwinpr-library0.1 libwinpr-path0.1 libwinpr-pool0.1 libwinpr-registry0.1
  libwinpr-rpc0.1 libwinpr-sspi0.1 libwinpr-synch0.1 libwinpr-sysinfo0.1 libwinpr-thread0.1 libwinpr-utils0.1 libwmf0.2-7 libwmf0.2-7-gtk libwnck-3-0 libwnck-3-common
  libwpd-0.10-10 libwps-0.4-4 libwww-perl libwxbase3.0-0v5 libwxbase3.0-dev libwxgtk3.0-0v5 libwxgtk3.0-dev libx264-148 libxapian30 libxatracker2 libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-dri2-0:i386
  libxcb-dri2-0-dev libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-dev libxcb-glx0 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-glx0-dev libxcb-present-dev libxcb-present0 libxcb-present0:i386
  libxcb-randr0 libxcb-randr0-dev libxcb-render0 libxcb-render0:i386 libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shape0 libxcb-shape0-dev libxcb-shm0 libxcb-shm0:i386 libxcb-shm0-dev
  libxcb-sync-dev libxcb-sync1 libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb-xfixes0 libxcb-xfixes0-dev libxcb-xinerama0 libxcb-xkb1 libxcb-xv0 libxcb1 libxcb1:i386 libxcb1-dev libxcursor-dev
  libxcursor1 libxcursor1:i386 libxdamage-dev libxdamage1 libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp-dev libxdmcp6 libxdmcp6:i386 libxenstore3.0 libxfont1 libxfont2 libxkbcommon-dev
  libxkbcommon-x11-0 libxkbcommon0 libxml2 libxml2:i386 libxml2-utils libxres1 libxslt1.1 libxslt1.1:i386 libxvmc1 libyaml-0-2 libyelp0 libykpers-1-1 libykpers-1-dev libzbar0
  libzeitgeist-2.0-0 libzmq5 libzmqpp4 light-themes lightdm lintian linux-base linux-firmware linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic login logrotate lshw lvm2
  manpages manpages-dev mesa-common-dev mesa-utils mesa-vdpau-drivers metacity-common mir-client-platform-mesa5 mir-graphics-drivers-desktop mixxx mixxx-data mlocate
  mobile-broadband-provider-info modemmanager mount mousetweaks mscompress msr-tools multiarch-support nano nautilus-sendto ndiff netcat-openbsd nettle-dev network-manager-dev
  network-manager-openvpn network-manager-pptp network-manager-pptp-gnome nload nmap notify-osd nplan ntfs-3g ntpdate nux-tools octave-doc octave-info openjdk-8-doc openjdk-8-jdk
  openjdk-8-jdk-headless openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jre-headless openjfx openprinting-ppds openssh-client openssl openvpn osinfo-db p11-kit p11-kit-modules p7zip p7zip-full passwd
  patch pciutils pcmciautils pcscd pdf2djvu pkg-config plymouth plymouth-label plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text poppler-data poppler-utils postfix
  postfix-sqlite printer-driver-foo2zjs printer-driver-foo2zjs-common printer-driver-gutenprint printer-driver-min12xxw printer-driver-pxljr psmisc pstoedit publicsuffix
  pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-utils pvm pvm-dev pyqt4-dev-tools python python-all python-all-dev python-apt-common python-bs4 python-cairo python-cffi
  python-cffi-backend python-chardet python-compizconfig python-concurrent.futures python-crypto python-cryptography python-dbus python-dev python-gi python-gi-cairo python-idna
  python-keyring python-keyrings.alt python-ldb python-librtmp python-libvirt python-libxml2 python-lxml python-minimal python-ndg-httpsclient python-pkg-resources python-qt4
  python-requests python-samba python-setuptools python-sip python-six python-talloc python-tdb python-urllib3 python2.7 python2.7-dev python2.7-minimal python3-apparmor
  python3-apport python3-bs4 python3-chardet python3-click-package python3-commandnotfound python3-cryptography python3-cupshelpers python3-distro-info python3-distupgrade
  python3-idna python3-jinja2 python3-jwt python3-keyring python3-keyrings.alt python3-launchpadlib python3-lazr.restfulclient python3-louis python3-mako python3-pkg-resources
  python3-problem-report python3-ptyprocess python3-pyatspi python3-requests python3-setuptools python3-six python3-software-properties python3-speechd python3-update-manager
  python3-urllib3 qemu-block-extra qemu-kvm qemu-system-common qemu-system-x86 qemu-utils qml-module-io-thp-pyotherside qml-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel
  qml-module-qt-labs-settings qml-module-qtmultimedia qml-module-qtsysteminfo qpdf qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin qtdeclarative5-test-plugin qttranslations5-l10n rake resolvconf
  rfkill rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist rsync rsyslog rtkit ruby-bundler ruby-mime-types ruby-minitest ruby-net-scp ruby-net-sftp ruby-net-ssh ruby-netrc ruby-nokogiri
  ruby-pkg-config ruby-rest-client ruby-sqlite3 ruby-test-unit ruby-thor ruby-unf-ext ruby2.3 samba-common samba-common-bin samba-libs sbsigntool screenfetch seabios
  sensible-utils session-migration session-shortcuts shotwell shotwell-common signon-ui-service signon-ui-x11 signond snapd snapd-login-service software-properties-common
  software-properties-gtk sound-theme-freedesktop speech-dispatcher speech-dispatcher-audio-plugins speech-dispatcher-espeak-ng sqlite3 squashfs-tools ssh-askpass-gnome ssl-cert
  strace sudo suru-icon-theme synergy syslinux-legacy sysstat system-config-printer system-config-printer-common system-config-printer-gnome system-config-printer-udev systemd
  systemd-sysv t1utils tar tcl8.6 tcpdump telepathy-mission-control-5 testdisk tex-common thermald thunderbird thunderbird-gnome-support thunderbird-locale-en
  thunderbird-locale-en-us time tk8.6 tmux totem totem-common totem-plugins transmission-common transmission-gtk ttf-ancient-fonts-symbola tzdata ubuntu-app-launch
  ubuntu-app-launch-tools ubuntu-artwork ubuntu-docs ubuntu-drivers-common ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-mobile-icons ubuntu-mono ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
  ubuntu-settings ubuntu-software ubuntu-standard ubuntu-wallpapers ubuntu-wallpapers-xenial ubuntu-wallpapers-yakkety ubuntu-wallpapers-zesty udev ufw unattended-upgrades
  unity-asset-pool unity-control-center unity-greeter unity-lens-files unity-lens-music unity-lens-photos unity-lens-video unity-scope-home unity-scope-video-remote
  unity-scopes-master-default unity-scopes-runner uno-libs3 unrar unzip update-manager update-manager-core update-notifier update-notifier-common upower ure ureadahead
  usb-modeswitch usb-modeswitch-data usbmuxd usbutils util-linux uuid-dev uuid-runtime va-driver-all vim vim-common vim-runtime vim-tiny virt-manager virt-viewer virtinst
  vulkan-utils wamerican wbritish wget whiptail whois whoopsie whoopsie-preferences wireless-tools wpasupplicant wx-common wx3.0-headers x11-common x11-session-utils x11-utils
  x11-xserver-utils xbrlapi xdg-user-dirs xdg-user-dirs-gtk xdg-utils xdiagnose xinit xinput xkb-data xmir xorg xsel xserver-common xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core
  xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-radeon xul-ext-ubufox xxd xz-utils
  yelp youtube-dl zeitgeist-core zeitgeist-datahub zenity zenity-common zip zlib1g zlib1g:i386 zlib1g-dev
1524 upgraded, 68 newly installed, 0 to remove and 172 not upgraded.
Need to get 1.118 MB of archives.
After this operation, 666 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

Comment: Will it actually upgrade to 17.10 without your explicit directive? Perhaps it's simply upgrading these packages in anticipation of when you finally do upgrade to 17.10!

Comment: Did you already start an upgrade, and kill the process in the middle before it downloaded and installed packages? What does your apt sources point to?

Comment: Thank you @dobey , that was it. It hat changed the sources.list already to Artful. Though i don't recall ever canceling an upgrade process. Fortunately there was a backup of the Zesty sources. If you want, write an answer and I'll mark it as correct.